# Number of points in number fields on curve of genus at least 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

A smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ of genus at least 2 has finitely many $K$-points for any number field $K$.

What functions from number fields to $\mathbb{N}$ come up as the number of points on such a curve? Are there restrictions on the growth rate with respect to degree/discriminant?

Comment: Yes, there are bounds coming from uniform versions of Faltings's theorem - conjecturally there is a bound depending only on the genus and the degree of the extension for how many points there are. See a recent overview [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.03431)